# Oracle APEX 21.2.0 display image from pl/sql function

Tags: oracle-apex, apex, apex-code

I want to show image of some person in display image item. I have pl/sql funtion in which i send imageDate and personId, and function returns blob. How can i display image using this function that returns blob or is there some other way to use return value from function an show it as image?

Comment: I googled  "oracle apex display image" and the first hit was a tutorial on how to do this. Have you tried anything ? Did you get errors ?

Comment: Maybe i didnt explain the best. I am not using report, i use just page item display image. I'am not using table from which i get data, so I cant use BlOB Column returned by SQL Statement. I need to show image that my PL/SQL function returned, and i havent find anywhere how to do that. I watched many tutorials  any of them was about something like that. So if you found it, can you please send me link :D

Comment: If it is a function just do ```SELECT <your_function(args)> FROM DUAL``` and then you can use BlOB Column returned by SQL Statement. What is the source of that function ? That probably is a SQL statement too - just use that ?

Comment: That works wery well, thank you, i didnt know that i can call function form dual like that. Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad to be of help